# Region for the footer not working, but the header is working

Tags: 8, theming

I have the following regions set up in my *.info.yml file:

```
name: Test
type: theme
description: 'Theme'
base theme: stable
core: 8.x
regions:
  header: 'Header'
  content: 'Content'
  footer: 'Footer'
libraries-override:
  system/base: false
```

In `page--front.html.twig`, I placed `{{ page.header }}` where I wanted the header to be, and noticed via Twig Debugging that Drupal was expecting a file named `region--header.html.twig`.  Great!

So, similarly, I did this for the footer.

`{{ page.footer }}` and `region--footer.html.twig` ... but it does not work!  Twig Debug's comments do not reveal any hook for the footer at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any blocks in the footer? The region won't be rendered if not

Comment: Hmm.. I am not sure. How would I check?

Comment: Pop to the block layout page (/admin/structure/block) - if it says _No blocks in this region_ under _Footer_, that's the problem :)

Comment: That's what it is.  Thank you.  Can you formally answer this question so it won't be unanswered?

Comment: Welcome and done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regions are only rendered by default if they contain blocks (of which at least one must have content).

You can check whether the *Footer* region has blocks assigned to it by visiting the Block Layout admin page at /admin/structure/block. If you see the *No blocks in this region* message under the *Footer* block, you know that's the problem.